# How do I get newly updated timezone data to be used, rather than the old one?

Tags: macos, command-line, timezone

My /var/db/timezone/tz/2021a.3.0/zoneinfo was updated to version 2022a on 18 March 2022.

The old one is still being read, that is 2021a.

The new links are shown here:–

````
total 0
lrwxr-xr-x  1 root  wheel   35  1 Nov 11:44 icutz -> /var/db/timezone/tz/2021a.3.0/icutz
drwxr-xr-x  4 root  wheel  128 25 Mar 22:06 tz
lrwxr-xr-x  1 root  wheel   29 25 Mar 22:06 tz_latest -> /var/db/timezone/tz/2022a.1.0
lrwxr-xr-x  1 root  wheel   38  1 Nov 11:44 zoneinfo -> /var/db/timezone/tz/2021a.3.0/zoneinfo```

I have no idea how to remove/recreate the zoneinfo link to point to /var/db/timezone/tz/2022a.1.0 nor any idea if the icutz entry needs to be changes as well :(

Note: the /var/db/timezone/tz fofolder now contains the 2 timezone folders, old and new:-

MacPRO:tz johnhall$ ls -l
total 0
drwxr-xr-x  5 root  wheel  160 26 Oct 11:30 2021a.3.0
drwxr-xr-x  5 root  wheel  160 18 Mar 14:28 2022a.1.0


I've come up with a solution. I guess it was as a failed TZ update from Apple this month.
disable SIP (Recovery mode, terminal : csrutil disable )
$ unlink /var/db/timezone/icutz
$ ln -Fs /var/db/timezone/tz/2022a.1.0/icutz /var/db/timezone/icutz
$ unlink /var/db/timezone/zoneinfo
$ ln -Fs /var/db/timezone/tz/2022a.1.0/zoneinfo /var/db/timezone/zoneinfo

My folders now look like this:-
MacPRO:~ johnhall$ cd /var/db/timezone
MacPRO:timezone johnhall$ ls -laOA@
total 0
dr-xr-xr-x@   6 root  wheel  restricted  192 27 Mar 19:41 .
    com.apple.rootless     8 
drwxr-xr-x  112 root  wheel  sunlnk     3584 27 Mar 19:38 ..
lrwxr-xr-x    1 root  wheel  restricted   35 27 Mar 19:40 icutz -> /var/db/timezone/tz/2022a.1.0/icutz
drwxr-xr-x    3 root  wheel  restricted   96 27 Mar 19:22 tz
lrwxr-xr-x    1 root  wheel  restricted   29 25 Mar 22:06 tz_latest -> /var/db/timezone/tz/2022a.1.0
lrwxr-xr-x    1 root  wheel  restricted   38 27 Mar 19:41 zoneinfo -> /var/db/timezone/tz/2022a.1.0/zoneinfo

MacPRO:timezone johnhall$ cd tz
MacPRO:tz johnhall$ ls -laOA@
total 0
drwxr-xr-x  3 root  wheel  restricted  96 27 Mar 19:22 .
dr-xr-xr-x@ 6 root  wheel  restricted 192 27 Mar 19:41 ..
    com.apple.rootless    8 
drwxr-xr-x  5 root  wheel  restricted 160 18 Mar 14:28 2022a.1.0
````

Comment: What version of macOS are you running?

Comment: 10.13.6 on an old MacPRO5,1.

Comment: My first guess is a failed instyall of macOS - get the combo updater and apply that

Answer (score 2):

Several of my macs are in the same state as related by the OP. (The macs are running 10.13.6, 10.15.7, and 11.6.5.)

On those macs, System Preferences / Date & Time / Time Zone says that "Updated time zone definitions are available and will be installed at the next restart".

Another 10.13.6 mac has updated info; I restarted it recently.

So, perhaps a restart is all that is needed.

Comment: See a picture in https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT203413

Comment: I had tried restarts to no avail. My solution worked.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you both for the comments.

My solution was to disable sip and recreate the links to the new 2022a.1.0 timezone folder.

Worked for me!